# Pass variable onto another variable in Python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to pass the value of fruit so that I can get it printed as `your fruit is apple` if apple is selected and `your fruit is apple orange` if both selected. Maybe I should be using array?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

def show():
    fruit=""
    if apple.get()==1:
        fruit = "apple"
    if orange.get()==1:
        fruit = "orange"
    
    msg = "your fruit is %s"%fruit
    print(msg)

Label(app, text="fruit selected").grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=W)
apple = IntVar()
Checkbutton(app, text="apple", variable=apple,command = show).grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W)
orange = IntVar()
Checkbutton(app, text="orange", variable=orange).grid(row=4,column=2, sticky=W)


#size
app.title('Basic message')
app.geometry("700x500")

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes make a global array

Comment: Also add command=show in 2nd checkbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many ways of doing this but lets first do it in your example. Just by adding one line and some improvements to your `show` function will give you the desired results.

```py
def show():
    fruit=""
    if apple.get() and orange.get():
        fruit = 'apple orange' 
    elif apple.get():
        fruit = "apple"
    elif orange.get():
        fruit = "orange"

    msg = "your fruit is %s"%fruit
    print(msg)
```

But the whole code can be improved, using a for loop to create different fruit `Checkbutton`s and saving their variable `IntVar` as `var` in their instance which will make it easy to access later, finally saving those Checkbuttons in a list to access them in `show` function. The logic is simple I'm just checking which checkbutton is ticked and add their text in the `fruit` variable.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
ckb_list = []

def show():
    f = ''
    for ckb in ckb_list:
        if ckb.var.get():
            f += ckb['text'] + ' '
    msg = "your fruit is %s"%f
    print(msg)

Label(app, text="fruit selected").grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=W)

for col, fruit in enumerate(('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango')):
    ckb = Checkbutton(app, text=fruit, command=show)
    ckb.var = ckb['variable'] = IntVar()
    ckb.grid(row=4,column=col+1, sticky=W)
    ckb_list.append(ckb)

#size
app.title('Basic message')
app.geometry("700x500")

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add command=show in orange checkbox.
Also it would be good to only print a message if one or more checkboxes are checked.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

def show():
    fruit=""
    if apple.get()==1:
        fruit = "apple"
    if orange.get()==1:
        fruit = "orange"
    
    if orange.get()==1 or apple.get()==1:
        msg = "your fruit is %s"%fruit
        print(msg)

Label(app, text="fruit selected").grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=W)
apple = IntVar()
Checkbutton(app, text="apple", variable=apple,command = show).grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W)
orange = IntVar()
Checkbutton(app, text="orange", variable=orange, command = show).grid(row=4,column=2, sticky=W)


#size
app.title('Basic message')
app.geometry("700x500")

app.mainloop()
```

I would also recommend to use a array or list, if you want to add more boxes.
You can also consider to use a class for better "variable management"